# How to find the port number for MMS agent

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I like to find out on which port MMS agent is running for Mongo. Please let me know how to find out. It is not defined on config file. It may be running on default port.

Comment: What do you mean by MMS Agent: MongoDB Cloud Manager, MongoDB Ops Manager, or something else? The Cloud/Ops Manager agents don't listen on a port; they make outbound connections to managed/monitored MongoDB instances and your Cloud/Ops Manager endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update. It is MongoDB Cloud Manager. I like to know if they use any port for connections like MongoDB database does. It looks it does not as per your answer.